# Integrating Lucene into a .NET desktop application

Tags: .net, full-text-search, lucene.net

I am making a .NET desktop application (WinForms+Local PostgreSQL Server) for managing sales in a small store.

I wish to integrate Lucene search facilities into the 'Product Search' module of my software. Are there any good patterns for integrating such Information Retrieval Libraries into existing applications?

Note : The application is still in development and I can always modify the architecture to integrate Lucene.

Note : I know how to use Lucene and have created a simple demo app to test it's capabilities.
I am only looking for patterns that integrate such search functionality into Desktop Applications.

Note : Also the main requirement of the integration is to enable the user to quickly search for products/brands/etc and provide a google autocomplete'esque system in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I have created a generic repository that's give you at some point some level of abstraction there's and also there's a project named [linq to lucene](http://linqtolucene.codeplex.com/) which perfectly matches the repository pattern, I've took some part of the code and I made my own implementation according to my needs, I suggest you to take a look, there's also a nuget package named [lucene contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/) which adds some more functionalities to lucene.net. package.

The good thing about using linq into your lucene implementation is that any avg developer will be able to do text search without having a deep knowledge of lucene.

talking about architecture is always recomended to consider the OOP prinicples like DRY, SOLID, TDD.
In my case I got a separate project something like companyName.Software.Lucene which abstracts all the mechanics behind lucene, and when you use that implementation, it feels like you're using at some point a ORM for doing searches.

in the case that you're using nHibernate theres an option to use text index set with it

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend in getting the book "Lucene in Action".  It is based on the Lucene 3.0.3 version for Java, HOWEVER that version happens to be the most current version for .NET (3.0.3).

That book will provide you with all you need to get going for .NET.  Implementing a "Google-like" search is actually not that trivial..having to do: fuzzy searches, thesaurus matching, spelling/did you mean, complex scoring etc.  I have been using Lucene for over 3 years and that book has helped me learn a lot.